# How to add Strings on X-Axis in iOS-charts 4.0.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts

I Stucked on my tryings to implement custom labels on xAxis in last update of ios Charts (4.0.3).

Have this code:

```
 // some model inside with parsed JSON, this is working well.
var dataRad = [DataModel]()
 var dataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
            
            
            for item in dataRad {
                guard let level = Double(item.level!), let id = Double(item.id!) else { return }
                let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: id, y: level)
                //   labels.append(item.temp!)
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
                
            }

// some setup of the Charts, e.g. colors etc.

let xAxis = chartsView.xAxis
            xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name:"Play-Bold", size:10)!
            xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
          
            xAxis.labelCount = self.dataRad.count
            xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
            let labels: [String] = ["1, 2", "2, 2", "3, 3", "4, 4", "5, 5", "6, 6", "7, 7", "8, 8", "9, 9", "10, 10"]
    
            xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: labels)
```

This code doesn't work. I can't see labels on my xAxis.
But if I delete this formatter, I see defaults values of my "id" var (in "for in" loop).

I've tried some tricks, like extensions, add. class with formatter.
Nothing works for me...

Please help to solve this problem with labels.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current setup for [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

```
        let labelFont = UIFont.SFProText(style: .bold, ofSize: 12)
        let lineWidth = CGFloat(1)

        // Setup style for X axis
        barChartView.xAxis.axisLineWidth = lineWidth
        barChartView.xAxis.labelFont = labelFont
        barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = .white
        barChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = .white
        
        barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

        barChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
        barChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
        barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

        barChartView.xAxis.spaceMax = 0
        barChartView.xAxis.spaceMin = 0
        barChartView.xAxis.decimals = 0
        barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
        barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        barChartView.xAxis.labelFont = labelFont
        barChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = .white
        barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = .white
```

Then you can try my `CustomIndexAxisFormatter`:

```
class CustomIndexAxisFormatter: NSObject, AxisValueFormatter {
    private var _values: [(Double, String)] = [(Double, String)]()
    private var _valueCount: Int = 0
    
    public var values: [(Double, String)] {
        get {
            return _values
        }
        set {
            _values = newValue
            _valueCount = _values.count
        }
    }
    
    public override init(){
        super.init()
    }
    
    public init(values: [(Double, String)]) {
        super.init()
        self.values = values
    }
    
    public static func with(values: [(Double, String)]) -> CustomIndexAxisFormatter? {
        return CustomIndexAxisFormatter(values: values)
    }
    
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if let firstIndex = self.values.firstIndex(where: { $0.0 == value }) {
            return _values[firstIndex].1
        }
        if value <= 1000 && values.indices.contains(Int(value)) {
            return _values[Int(value)].1
        } else {
            guard let axis = axis else {
                return ""
            }

            let count = Double(self._valueCount)
            let diff = value - axis.axisMinimum
            let range = axis.axisRange
            let step = range / (count - 1)
            let index = Int(round(diff / step))
            guard values.indices.contains(index) else { return "" }
            return _values[index].1
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you make dataSet:

```
        let labels: [String] = ["1, 2", "2, 2", "3, 3", "4, 4", "5, 5", "6, 6", "7, 7", "8, 8", "9, 9", "10, 10"]
        var arrayXLabel: [(Double, String)] = []
        for (index, item) in entries.enumerated() {
            if index < labels.count - 1 {
                // need to use item.x as Double value of Array label
                // because we will need to link label with chart point properly
                arrayXLabel.append((item.x, labels[index]))
            }
        }
        barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = CustomIndexAxisFormatter(values: arrayXLabel ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm a new to Charts.
I have an array from strings only. It doesn't work for my model :(

` struct Rad: Decodable {
 let id : String?
 let level : String?
 let temp : String?
 let date : String?
 let time : String?
} `

Comment: The important thing is that your dataEntries need to have same number of elements as your array that you put into CustomIndexAxisFormatter.

And you need to put the Double value of X from Entry (best method is having same value with Entry for the IndexAxis's array X label), This double value will be used to identify correctly the label from array. 

It seems to you didn't understand the mechanic. Let me update the code with your model.

Comment: I've got this error: Tuple type '(String?, String)' is not convertible to tuple type '(Double, String)'

Comment: This error shows you clearly an issue that you need to do. 
It is a very basic syntax issue of Swift.
I updated my answer, please check the last part.

Comment: Thank you. Trying to implement this code. Let you know. Thank you for your time!